# How to insert multiple consecutive columns with empty values to python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `stations` with four columns "1990", "2000", "2006", and "2012" with area data. To interpolate the years in between I want to insert columns with empty values in the gaps.

I did use `pandas.DataFrame.insert` to insert columns at specific locations but couldn't find out how to do that with multiple columns like `pandas.DataFrame.insert[1, ["1991":"1999"], np.nan]`.

Is there a way to insert multiple columns with a consecutive number/name to fill the gaps?
I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't hear this often for question about pandas, but in this instance, I think looping is probably the clearest solution:

```
for year in range(1991, 2000):
    df[str(year)] = np.NaN.
```

You can then reorder the columns afterwards.